# Backbone view drawing from two models

Tags: backbone.js

Just looking for a way to use two models within one view (or a better idea).

I have a **Product**, with a set of **Attributes**. The **Attributes** are to be selected from a pre-defined list. So, I'd need to grab a list of the **Attribute** choices, then a list of the attributes that are selected for my **Product**. I have two API endpoints to grab both lists `/attributes/` and `/product/123/attributes/`.

How best to achieve this? I'd need to render out the choices from the first endpoint, then use the second endpoint to show which ones are selected, then listen for the `choose` action (i.e. a checkbox being ticked).

Or anther way would be to have every **Attribute** linked with every **Product**, and a flag to say `selected` or not, but that seems a bit of a back to front way of doing things... but certainly the easiest to implement from the front-end.

Backend is Django/Postgres by the way if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can help you here is having an Attributes Collection inside your Product model where you can store all the attributes that correspond to the model. You can initialize a Collection inside a model like this:

```
var Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    var attributes = new Attributes();
  }
})
```

When you initialize the view pass an Atributes Collection, filled with all the attributes grabbed from `/attributes`, and a blank Product model (or have it initialized when you create the view). Then when a user selects an attribute from the list an event can be trigger that would add it to the product attributes collection.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hmm - I went with a middle way. Have the ProductAttributes api endpoint display all choices and if they're selected or not on the fly. Not storing it all in the db. Might be that to scale I need to store it in the db, but for now this works.